# Blur event on textbox which is inside a table for particular row only not for all rows in table

Tags: jquery, onblur

```
$(function()
{
$('#tableId').on('blur','td',function(event) {
      alert('Hi');
});
});
```

Above code works but the function iterates all the rows of the table every time when I make change in a single row only (I want the row only in which textbox value is changed not all the rows in table at a time).

Comment: Consider adding a codepen or jsfiddler...

Comment: `on` closure always take the correct selector. You should do the alert on textbox changes callback.

Comment: can you post some html too?

Comment: I m using datatables.net js with textbox in grid. I want to know which textbox's value is entered or updated in which row...

Comment: @NikhilPatel if you can create a fiddle this will be a lot easier,

Answer (score 0):

These are a few options I can think.

---

1. Give your tr an ID. So in your selector you will only select the row with ID.

   ```
   <table id='tableId'>
   <tr id='rowId'>
       <td><td>
       <td><td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td><td>
       <td><td>
   </tr>
   ```

   ```
   $('#rowID td').on('blur',function(event) {
   alert('Hi');
   });
   ```

---

2. Give a class name for the affected td's so in your selector you will only select the tds' that belong to that class

   ```
    <table id='tableId'>
       <tr>
           <td class="tdClass"><td>
           <td class="tdClass"><td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td><td>
           <td><td>
       </tr>
   </table>
   ```

   `$('.tdClass').on('blur','td',function(event) {`

**Edit**
In datatable you can override the callback after creating each row:

```
var table = $('#example').dataTable({
    ....
    'fnCreatedRow': function (nRow, aData, iDataIndex) {
        // Here you can check what specific rows to have this id
        if (iDataIndex == 1)
           $(nRow).attr('id', 'specificID'); 
    },
    ....
});
```

You can also add id to specific row using jquery.

```
$('#table tr:last').attr('id','lastRowID'); // For last Row
$('#table tr:first').attr('id','lastRowID'); // For first Row
$('#table tr:nth-child(1)').attr('id','lastRowID'); // For first Row remember nth-child starts from index 1 not like an array that starts with 0.
```

Comment: I cant use id on tr as its datatables.net grid therefore id will be same for all trs... And giving class to td won't help as i have tried already cause it gives value of the td but not the id of the row.

Comment: @NikhilPatel datatable js you mean? I knew that we can add id or class to datatable.

Comment: I know we can give class & id to datatables but assigning id to tr is not worth as all rows of datatables will get that same id. Do you have any solution to this please provide. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but my grid is dynamic & has around 100 rows or more. so I cant set id to all as its dynamic... The main thing is to get event on only the row in which text box is edited not all rows in grid.

Comment: @NikhilPatel ok what kind of event you are trying to achieve, lets be specific

Comment: Its in my question.